# Using UISplitViewController with UIDocument

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, uidocument

I am developing a Document based application (Imagine something like Keynote, with a table view containing the slides and a right part as editor). I would like to use the `UISplitViewController` as main View Controller for my document.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any example to achieve this. All the examples I have are using Storyboard and are not using `UIDocument`.

Any idea how I should do?

Comment: I'm now struggling with a similar situation. Could you please share how you managed this?